# Fetching tweets from my twitter account not working though posting a tweet works

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Am trying to get tweets from my twitter account using the Twitter API but all combinations keep on failing. With all node_modules present and everything seeming fine I get an error. Here is the full code:

```
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

//Retrieving tweets
client.get('statuses/show/:id_str', {'id_str':'749000808381968384'}, function (error, tweet, response) {
  if (error){
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(tweet);
    // console.log(response); // Raw response object.}
}});
```

Here is the error:
**`[ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ]`**

Kindly help by correcting the problem in the code, I have tried my best to look for answers from other sources in vain

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I found the answer from [twitter npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter). This is the code to use:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});

var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs'};
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);
  }
});
```

Screen name is your username. The one that begins with @ on your twitter profile.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint that you are using statuses/show/:id_str is to fetch the status specified by id_str and not the statuses of the user.

You should use the endpoint statuses/user_timeline to get the tweets of the authenticated users.

You could try the code suggested by Eric.